# AWS Lex and Facebook - content type

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, aws-lambda, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am working on AWS Lex, where I integrated it with FB Messenger successfully.

As I know so far, "responseCard" has only one "contentType"

```
 "responseCard": {
   "version": integer-value,
   "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
```

In FB Messenger, there are 4 different content types: audio, file, image, video
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/contenttypes

My question: how many are content types of "responseCard"?

What I want to achieve is bot replies gif file which will be played automatically. Example: GIPHY bot

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The possible contentType value is only generic.
Based on this source http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_ResponseCard.html

The result in messenger will be just an static image and not GIF